# How should I format a namespace with all different linked lists?

Tags: c++, linked-list, namespaces

I want make a very simple namespace 'list' kind of like 'std' with libraries like 'singly' and 'doubly'. How can I modular the code so that I can only use variables I need to (circular vs non-circular)?

I imagine that I can just add a 'struct node* prev' to the struct that the list is using, but if the user decides to not do circular, it would always be 'nullptr' causing in an unnecessary variable. The second way I imagine is with having 2 different classes...

```
namespace list{
    struct snode{
        int data;
        struct snode* next;
    };

    class singly{
        public:
            singly();
            singly(unsigned long long amount=0, bool circular=0, bool userCreated=0, bool empty=0);
            ~singly();

            void create(unsigned long long amount=0, bool circular=0, bool userCreated=0, bool empty=0);
            void display();
            void destroy();
        private:
            snode* HEAD;
            unsigned long long amount;

            bool empty;
            bool circular;
            snode* TAIL;
    };
}
```

I expect with this namespace to do the following..

```
include "singly.h"

using namespace list;

singly list;

list.create(5);

list.display();

list.destroy();
```

or by not using the namespace something else...

```
list::singly list(7, 1, 0, 1);

list.display();

list.~list();
```

While this isn't an assignment or anything, I want this to be my go-to when I need to create a linked list ever in my life. Eventually, I want to create a namespace 'tree' and have further expansion with that. I almost want this to be as easy to use as the 'string' abstract data type.

Comment: ***I want this to be my go-to when I need to create a linked list ever in my life*** Once you leave academics you should never do this in real life. Instead prefer to use `std::vector` or one of the containers in the standard library like `std::list`

Comment: How `struct node* prev` related to circular ? (I see for double link list). For circular `TAIL->next == HEAD` whereas non circular would have `TAIL->next == nullptr`.

Comment: unrelated: I would move `struct snode` inside `singly`and make it `private`. No one else needs to know about it and it's now One less thing cluttering the namespace

Comment: `list.~list();` is almost always the wrong thing to do and here it's going to be fatal. Don't destroy Automatic variables. Change their scope so the compiler destroys them for you when you want them gone. In general don't manually call the destructor. There are only a few cases where this is the right thing to do. Placement `new` is likely the most prominent of these cases.

Comment: as soon as you replace 'namespace' with the 'class', it might work. Class can be used for encapsulations of other classes and can play a role of a namespace this way.

Answer (score 0):

## short answer

It’s impossible

## long answer

I lied(ish).
Create a base strict containing data, then create snode that inherits the data, implementing the pointer of base class. When going through the list check whether it fails.

```
struct A {
    int data;
    // make it polymorphic for the conversion
    virtual void function() {return;}
};

struct B : A {
    struct A* next;
};

int main()
{
    struct A end;
    struct B beginning;
    beginning.next = &end;
    struct B* buffer = &beginning;
    while(true) {
        buffer = dynamic_cast<struct B*>(buffer->next);
        if (buffer == nullptr) break;
    }
}
```

## why it’s pretty irrelevant

You only save at most (0 bytes) of memory per list.
You save it using struct A, but struct A effectively has a function ptr/address aswell, which takes up space. This, however may be fixed by the compiler. And it takes longer to write worse code and the overall efficiency will be worse.

Comment: And `virtual` add also its overhead (mainly a hidden pointer). So you in fact add extra overhead.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about functions being loaded into memory! Thanks, I’ll edit it.